# Agregar un objeto a un vector a través de una función en c++

Tags: c++, vectores

tengo una clase llamada Pokémon, en la cual defino un vector y algunos atributos, el vector  almacenara varios Pokémon o esa es la idea. Tengo una función que se supone agrega los Pokémon, el problema viene cuando quiero agregar un objeto de esta clase en cada una de las posiciones del vector ya que me arroja un error diciendo que la funcion no es del tipo Pokémon más exactamente el siguiente:
error: request for member 'addPokemon' in 'miPokemon', which is of non-class type 'Pokemon()'

Dejo la clase, la funcion, y el llamado a la funcion. Aclaro que la clase Pokemon y la funcion estan en un archivo Pokemon.h y el llamado lo hago en una funcion main por separado.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Pokemon{
private:
    int identificadorPokemon;
    string nombrePokemon;
    int generacionPokemon;
    string tipoPokemon; 
    
    
    
    
public:
//#region Constructor
    vector<Pokemon> vectorPokemons;
    Pokemon(){};
    Pokemon(int prmIdentificadorPokemon, string prmNombrePokemon,
            int prmGeneracionPokemon, string prmTipoPokemon){
        
        
            this -> identificadorPokemon = prmIdentificadorPokemon;
            this -> nombrePokemon = prmNombrePokemon;
            this -> generacionPokemon = prmGeneracionPokemon;
            this -> tipoPokemon= prmTipoPokemon;
            //vectorPokemons = new vector<Pokemon>;
    };

            
//#region Setters
            
    void SetIdentificadorPokemon(int prmId){
        identificadorPokemon = prmId;
        
    }
    void SetNombrePokemon(int prmId)
    {
        identificadorPokemon = prmId;
    }
    void SetNombrePokemon(string prmNombrePokemon)
    {
        nombrePokemon = prmNombrePokemon;
    }
    
    void SetGeneracionPokemon(int prmGeneracionPokemon)
    {
        generacionPokemon = prmGeneracionPokemon;
    }
    
    void SetTipoPokemon(string prmTipoPokemon)
    {
        tipoPokemon = prmTipoPokemon;
    }
    void Set_Lista_Pokemons( vector<Pokemon> vectorPokemons)
    {
        this ->vectorPokemons = vectorPokemons;
    }
    
    
    int GetIdentificadorPokemon()
    {
        return identificadorPokemon;
    }
    string GetNombrePokemon()
    {
        return nombrePokemon;
    }
    int GetGeneracionPokemon()
    {
        return generacionPokemon;
    }
    string GetTipoPokemon()
    {
        return tipoPokemon;
    }
    
    vector<Pokemon> GetListaPokemones(){
        return vectorPokemons;
    }
//# endregion
    
        
    void addPokemon(Pokemon pokemon)
    {
        vectorPokemons.push_back(pokemon);
    }
};
```

Aqui el llamado

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Pokemon.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string nombrePokemon;
    int identificadorPokemon;
    int generacionPokemon;
    string tipoPokemon; 
    
    Pokemon miPokemon();
    
    cout<<"Ingresar el nombre de pokemon: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,nombrePokemon);
    cout<<"Ingresar el identificador de pokemon: "<<endl;
    cin>>identificadorPokemon;
    cout<<"Ingresar la generacion de pokemon: "<<endl;
    cin>>generacionPokemon;
    cout<<"Ingresar el tipo de pokemon: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,tipoPokemon);
    miPokemon.addPokemon(identificadorPokemon,nombrePokemon,generacionPokemon,tipoPokemon);
    
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Hay 2 problemas.

- Al poner paréntesis luego del nombre de la variable, el compilador interpreta que estás declarando una función:

  ```
  Pokemon miPokemon();
  ```

  Simplemente quítalos.

  Lo mismo sucede con el string `tipoPokemon`.
- La función `void addPokemon(Pokemon pokemon)` espera un `Pokemon`. Pero en la función `main` recibe otros parámetros:

  ```
  miPokemon.addPokemon(identificadorPokemon,nombrePokemon,generacionPokemon,tipoPokemon);
  ```

  Lo que puedes hacer es construir un Pokémon y pasarle ese nuevo Pokémon como parámetro:

  ```
  Pokemon nuevo(identificadorPokemon,nombrePokemon,generacionPokemon,tipoPokemon);
  miPokemon.addPokemon(nuevo);
  ```

---

También quería mencionar que creo que estás un poco confundido.

Es mejor si una clase tiene un único propósito. En este caso, una clase `Pokemon` que contenga información sobre un Pokémon.

Con esto quiero decir que el `vector` vaya a otra parte. Porque la clase `Pokemon` solo se debería hacer cargo de un solo Pokémon.

Así:

```
class Pokemon{
private:
    int identificadorPokemon;
    string nombrePokemon;
    int generacionPokemon;
    string tipoPokemon;
    
public:

    Pokemon(){}
    Pokemon(int prmIdentificadorPokemon, string prmNombrePokemon,
            int prmGeneracionPokemon, string prmTipoPokemon){
        
        
            this -> identificadorPokemon = prmIdentificadorPokemon;
            this -> nombrePokemon = prmNombrePokemon;
            this -> generacionPokemon = prmGeneracionPokemon;
            this -> tipoPokemon= prmTipoPokemon;
    };
            
    void SetIdentificadorPokemon(int prmId){
        identificadorPokemon = prmId; 
    }

    void SetNombrePokemon(int prmId)
    {
        identificadorPokemon = prmId;
    }

    void SetNombrePokemon(string prmNombrePokemon)
    {
        nombrePokemon = prmNombrePokemon;
    }
    
    void SetGeneracionPokemon(int prmGeneracionPokemon)
    {
        generacionPokemon = prmGeneracionPokemon;
    }
    
    void SetTipoPokemon(string prmTipoPokemon)
    {
        tipoPokemon = prmTipoPokemon;
    }

    int GetIdentificadorPokemon()
    {
        return identificadorPokemon;
    }

    string GetNombrePokemon()
    {
        return nombrePokemon;
    }

    int GetGeneracionPokemon()
    {
        return generacionPokemon;
    }

    string GetTipoPokemon()
    {
        return tipoPokemon;
    }
};
```

Y en el `main` o en otra parte pones el vector:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string nombrePokemon;
    int identificadorPokemon;
    int generacionPokemon;
    string tipoPokemon; 
    
    vector<Pokemon> pokemons;
    
    ...
    
    Pokemon nuevo(identificadorPokemon,nombrePokemon,generacionPokemon,tipoPokemon);
    pokemons.push_back(nuevo);
}
```